# How to get dates of last 4 weeks Monday and Sunday in php?

Tags: php, date

I am trying to generate Dates of `Monday` and `Sunday` of `each week` for last 4-8 weeks using PHP's `Date function`.

i have tried getting it like this.

```
<?php
$dates_array = array();

$dates_array['-3 week monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Last Monday - 3 week"));
$dates_array['-3 week sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Last Sunday - 3 week"));

$dates_array['-2 week monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Last Monday - 2 week"));
$dates_array['-2 week sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Last Sunday - 2 week"));

$dates_array['last monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Last Monday"));
$dates_array['last sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Last Sunday"));

$dates_array['this monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday"));
$dates_array['this sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday"));

print_r($dates_array);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [-3 week monday] => 2016-05-16
    [-4 week sunday] => 2016-05-15
    [-2 week monday] => 2016-05-30
    [-2 week sunday] => 2016-05-29
    [-1 week monday] => 2016-06-06
    [-1 week sunday] => 2016-06-05
    [last monday] => 2016-06-06
    [last sunday] => 2016-06-12
    [this monday] => 2016-06-13
    [this sunday] => 2016-06-19
)
```

and output i am getting is all correct for this week and last week, but before last week, everything is messed up, whys is that ?

i even tried like this way.

```
<?php
$dates_array = array();

$dates_array['-3 week monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday", strtotime('-3 week')));
$dates_array['-3 week sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday", strtotime('-3 week')));

$dates_array['-2 week monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday", strtotime('-2 week')));
$dates_array['-2 week sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday", strtotime('-2 week')));

$dates_array['last monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday", strtotime('-1 week')));
$dates_array['last sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday", strtotime('-1 week')));

$dates_array['this monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday"));
$dates_array['this sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday"));

print_r($dates_array);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [-3 week monday] => 2016-05-30
    [-3 week sunday] => 2016-05-29
    [-2 week monday] => 2016-06-06
    [-2 week sunday] => 2016-06-05
    [last monday] => 2016-06-13
    [last sunday] => 2016-06-12
    [this monday] => 2016-06-20
    [this sunday] => 2016-06-19
)
```

In above example too ,the output dates are weird.

so whats the best approach to get Dates of `Monday` and `Sunday` of `each week` for last 4-8 weeks using PHP.

using : PHP Version 5.3.3

---

UPDATE :

i have managed to get the proper dates as suggested by jeroen, but using same date function, like this

```
<?php

$dates_array = array();

$dates_array['-4 week monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday", strtotime('this week -4 week')));
$dates_array['-4 week sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday", strtotime('this week -4 week')));

$dates_array['-3 week monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday", strtotime('this week -3 week')));
$dates_array['-3 week sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday", strtotime('this week -3 week')));

$dates_array['-2 week monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday", strtotime('this week -2 week')));
$dates_array['-2 week sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday", strtotime('this week -2 week')));

$dates_array['last monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday", strtotime('last week')));
$dates_array['last sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday", strtotime('last week')));

$dates_array['this monday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday", strtotime('this week')));
$dates_array['this sunday'] = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Sunday", strtotime('this week')));

print_r($dates_array);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [-4 week monday] => 2016-05-16
    [-4 week sunday] => 2016-05-22
    [-3 week monday] => 2016-05-23
    [-3 week sunday] => 2016-05-29
    [-2 week monday] => 2016-05-30
    [-2 week sunday] => 2016-06-05
    [last monday] => 2016-06-06
    [last sunday] => 2016-06-12
    [this monday] => 2016-06-13
    [this sunday] => 2016-06-19
)
```

Comment: If you can get the information for this or last week already, you should put it in a `DateTime` object. Then you can easily substract intervals of 7 days. That works from php 5.3 on (although you might want to update to a more recent - maintained - version...).

Comment: thanks, i have managed to get proper dates using this week, updating to current version is also in todo. but it will take some to update code accordingly.

Comment: @AMB: can you close this question by accepting some answer, or comment on them?

Comment: @Glavić sure, give me few hours , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could this function:

```php
function getWeekMonSun($weekOffset) {
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->setIsoDate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W') + $weekOffset);
    return array(
        'Mon' => $dt->format('Y-m-d'),
        'Sun' => $dt->modify('+6 day')->format('Y-m-d'),
    );
}
```

which will return Monday and Sunday of the offset week.

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/592139)**</kbd>

Comment: thanks, this is best solution , works like charm. you should also add example in the answer.,

Answer (score 3):

Using timestamps and the date function:

```
<?php
$timestamp = strtotime('20160604');

$day_of_the_week = date('N', $timestamp); // N returns mon-sun as digits 1 - 7. 

$sunday_ts = $timestamp + ( 7 - $day_of_the_week) * 24 * 60 * 60;
$monday_ts = $timestamp - ( $day_of_the_week - 1) * 24 * 60 * 60;

$dates = array();
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $dates_key = '-' . $i . ' Week';
    $dates[$dates_key] = array(
        'Monday' => date('Y m d', $monday_ts - $i * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60),
        'Sunday' => date('Y m d', $sunday_ts - $i * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60)
        );
}

printf("Given date %s falls on a %s.\n", date('Y m d', $timestamp), date('l', $timestamp));
var_export($dates);
```

Output:

```
Given date 2016 06 04 falls on a Saturday.
array (
  '-1 Week' => 
  array (
    'Monday' => '2016 05 23',
    'Sunday' => '2016 05 29',
  ),
  '-2 Week' => 
  array (
    'Monday' => '2016 05 16',
    'Sunday' => '2016 05 22',
  ),
  '-3 Week' => 
  array (
    'Monday' => '2016 05 09',
    'Sunday' => '2016 05 15',
  ),
  '-4 Week' => 
  array (
    'Monday' => '2016 05 02',
    'Sunday' => '2016 05 08',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following ways by reducing today with multiples of 7

```
    // This Week
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Monday"))."<br>";
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Sunday"))."<br>";

    // Last Week
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Monday -7 day"))."<br>";
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Sunday -7 day"))."<br>";

    // -2 Week
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Monday -14 day"))."<br>";
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Sunday -14 day"))."<br>";

    // -3 Week
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Monday -21 day"))."<br>";
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Sunday -21 day"))."<br>";

    // -4 Week
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Monday -28 day"))."<br>";
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Sunday -28 day"))."<br>";

    // -5 Week
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Monday -35 day"))."<br>";
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Sunday -35 day"))."<br>";

    // -6 Week
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Monday -42 day"))."<br>";
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Sunday -42 day"))."<br>";

    // -7 Week
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Monday -49 day"))."<br>";
    echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("this Sunday -49 day"))."<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than subtracting days with week, use number of days with current date as shown below.

```
 <?php
    date('Y-m-d',strtotime("Monday"));
    echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday  days'));
    echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday -7 days'));
    echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday -14 days'));
    echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday -21 days'));
    echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last monday -28 days'));
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a table of dates with dates broken down, eg.;

```
date - '2005-01-01', 
day - 'Saturday',
day-number -  1, 
month number -1, 
month - 'January', 
year number - 2005,
dt formated -  20050101
```

it from 1st Jan 2005 to 2049. so it makes doing stuff like what you need super simple. in this case i would simply use;

> SELECT dt FROM `000_00_Calender` WHERE `dt` between CURDATE()-30 and
>   CURDATE() and `dt_day` in ('Monday','Sunday')

if you like, you can get the file [here](http://rsdisk.com/000_00_Calender.sql). it is a .sql (1.12mb)

sample;

> INSERT INTO `000_00_Calender` (`recID`, `dt`, `dt_day`, `day_number`,
>   `month_number`, `month_word`, `dt_year`, `date_formated`, `verified`)
>   VALUES (1, '2005-01-01', 'Saturday', 1, 1, 'January', 2005, 20050101,
>   '-'), (2, '2005-01-02', 'Sunday', 2, 1, 'January', 2005, 20050102,
>   '-'), (3, '2005-01-03', 'Monday', 3, 1, 'January', 2005, 20050103,
>   '-'), (4, '2005-01-04', 'Tuesday', 4, 1, 'January', 2005, 20050104,
>   '-'), (5, '2005-01-05', 'Wednesday', 5, 1, 'January', 2005, 20050105,
>   '-'),.....